# Is it possible to recover a deleted file from a project written in Spyder 5.1.5?

Tags: python, file, version, spyder, recover

I would like to hear that for the  Spyder 5.1.5 version is now it possible to recover an accidentally deleted files from a project. If it is, I would really appreciate how to do it because I am pretty worried about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a simple solution: keep your project or working directory in Google Drive, so a deleted file can be recovered from Google Drive's trash, even if the deleted file is not in Window's trash.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as far as I know.
If you're running on Mac, try to recover via TimeMachine, as it does snapshots every hour or maintain the working folder synchronized with a cloud service.